# Subclassing a Python class, many of whose methods create new instances of the same class

Tags: python, xml, subclass, mixins, beautifulsoup

I'd like to extend a Python (2.7) class that handles HTML or XML structures. At the moment I'm fiddling with bs4, but that's probably not essential to this question.

I want to add a bunch of functions that do higher-level operations; say, manipulating entire table columns, sorting list subelements, etc. So I define a subclass

```
class myBS4 (bs4.BeautifulSoup):
    def sortChildren(self, keyPath,...):
    ...
```

Fine so far. But the original class (and related ones like Tag, NavigableString, etc.) already have various methods that instantiate bs4 objects, such as new_tag() to make a "Tag" (Element), new_string() to make a NavigableString (Text node), etc. Same with DOM-based classes, or probably any package that handles recursive data structures.

Does that mean that I have to find every place in every bs4-related class that instantiates a bs4-related object, and subclass and override so they all instantiate my class instead? That seems awfully tedious.

Worse, it seems very prone to subtle bugs. For example, the bs4 constructor constructs a quasi-DOM tree from parsed HTML or XML; but it may or may not call new_tag() while doing so. It may just say something like

```
x = Tag("div")
```

In which case, I'd get instances of BeautifulSoup and Tag and NavigableString objects, mixed into my tree of myBS4 and myTag and myNavigableString objects. Calls would then fail when asked to do an extended operation on a non-extended node.

So overriding new_tag(), etc. may not suffice; the only way to know if you got all cases is to study (or grep) the entire bs4 implementation. And a bs4 update might be pretty likely to break it even though there's really no conceptual reason to touch bs4 itself at all.

Is there any clean way around this issue? I thought about mixins, but as far as I can tell I'd still have to subclass bs4 to pull in the mixin, so it wouldn't help. Am I completely missing something?

Comment: You could create subclasses of all of the BS4 classes (potentially using a mixin class to add the extended methods), then monkey-patch these classes into the BS4 module.

Comment: Just monkey-patching the new methods in seems to be working pretty well. No subclassing at all, just path the original class. That way, any time the original code instantiates a bs4 object, it's still the right thing.